# What does it mean for a function $u : D \to \mathbb{C}$ to be harmonic, $D \subset \mathbb{R^2}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

On page 167 of David Ullrich's "Complex Made Simple", he defines $u : D \to \mathbb{C}$ to be harmonic, $D \subset \mathbb{R^2}$, to be harmonic in $D$ if it is twice continuously real differentiable and $u_{xx} = u_{yy}$.

Since $\mathbb{R^2} = \mathbb{C}$, does this mean that $u$ is a function from $D$ to $\mathbb{R^2}$, and so $u(x,y) = (f(x,y),g(x,y))$? Then, what does $u_{xx}$ mean for a vector valued function?

Comment: ? [Harmonic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_function) no longer means $\Delta u=0$, hence $u_{xx}=-u_{yy}$ in this case...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $u=(f,g)$, then $u_{xx} = (f_{xx},g_{xx})$.  That is, do it component-wise.

Comment: Thanks! A quick question: the codomain $\mathbb{C}$ can be interchanged with $\mathbb{R^2}$ in this case, right?

Comment: Yes, you can identify $\mathbb C$ with $\mathbb R^2$.  However it is quite likely that the book will later make use of the multiplicative structure on $\mathbb C$, and then the identification will be less helpful.

Comment: If I don't identify $\mathbb{C}$ with $\mathbb{R^2}$, does that mean that $u(x,y) = f(x,y) + ig(x,y)$ and $u_{xx} = f_{xx} + ig_{xx}$?

Comment: Yes.  (I need a certain number of characters in each comment, so ignore what is in the parentheses.)